# Top IPs used output traffic for last month - Debian

Tags: linux, debian, monitoring, traffic

I have server running Debian 11 and it is a webserver, I need to know in a specific period what is the IP that utlize more traffic out from the server, I find some tools like iftop and vnstat, but I cannot find what I need, I need a tool to keep data for network traffic for specific time and I can find which IP is consume high traffic from my server

Thanks

Comment: So you keep apache logs from last month?

Comment: Awstats is a bit basic but simpl, available from repo and will fulfill your requirements as long as you are happy with its month based reporting periods

Comment: To expand on the other comments: when your web server maintains access logs you can use the information stored in those to generate visitor / usage statistics. Note that such stats don't include traffic generated via any other protocol: if your webmaster has copied lots of data over (s)ftp or scp for example ; that won't be included in the apache logs. If/when you need statistics for all possible protocols: consider ipt-netflow  to generate netflow data and capture/import  that into a suitable analyser

Comment: to describe my problem in more details. the server is running multiple services, web, DNS and mail, so what I need is to monitor all traffic on the server on all ports and which IPs is utilizing the bandwidth for specific period, so if there is a tool like zabbix but to show me which IPs is using more bandwidth in specific period